# Regex to find match any combination of 3 terms

Tags: regex

I need to design a regex which will match any combination of n words, without duplicates.

E.g. the regex for the words `"she"` `"is"` `"happy"` would match `"she is happy"`, `"happy she is"` but not `"she is is happy"` or `"she is"`.

Can I do this with Regex for should I use a custom algorithm?

Comment: Does it have to be done with RegEx?

Comment: I too agree with @WaiHaLee, It is simply getting the list of words for the input text and checking if the list contains all required terms

Comment: No it doesn't.  I just figured a regex engine is likely to be more efficient than whatever I write. My fallback is to do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

This match `she is happy` in any order but not duplicate word:

```
^(?=(?:(?!\bshe\b).)*\bshe\b(?:(?!\bshe\b).)*$)(?=(?:(?!\bis\b).)*\bis\b(?:(?!\bis\b).)*$)(?=(?:(?!\bhappy\b).)*\bhappy\b(?:(?!\bhappy\b).)*$).*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/0GaV1I/1)

Let's explain the first part (i.e. `(?=(?:(?!\bshe\b).)*\bshe\b(?:(?!\bshe\b).)*$)`)

This make sure we have **one and only one** "she" anywhere in the phrase.

```
(?=                     # start lookahead
    (?:                 # non capture group
        (?!\bshe\b)     # negative lookahead, make sure we don't have "she"
        .               # any character
    )*                  # end group, may appear 0 or more times
    \bshe\b             # literally "she" surounded by word boundaries
    (?:                 # non capture group
        (?!\bshe\b)     # negative lookahead, make sure we don't have "she"
        .               # any character
    )*                  # end group, may appear 0 or more times
    $
)
```

Same explanation for the other words "is" and "happy".